# Sending array of data in php to display in email

Tags: php, url

I have a application form that accepts array of data. The data is stored efficiently on DB but when I try to put this whole data to my email address. Just the details general details like name, phone number, address are saved. multiple levels of data stored in array are not shown in email, instead they are displayed as "array".

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"]))
        { 

            $datetime = $_POST["datetime"];
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $dept = $_POST["dept"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $phone = $_POST["phone"];
            $comments = $_POST["comments"];

            $cnt = count($_POST['model']);
            for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){             
            $model = $_POST["model"][$i];
            $tag = $_POST["tag"][$i];
            $itemdesc = $_POST["itemdesc"][$i];

            $Query = "INSERT INTO ssubmit (datetime, name, dept, email, phone, comments, model, outag, itemdesc) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$dept', '$email', '$phone',  '$comments', '$model', '$tag', '$itemdesc')";
            $Result = mysql_query($Query, $Link) or die(mysql_error());
       }
```

//php code to retrieve the values

```
foreach($_POST as $var => $value)

{

echo $var . ': <b>' . $value . "</b> \r\n";

}
```

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.  You can also see http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives and explanation of the danger.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I will consider your tip and try to upgrade my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the values of arrays to output the data, similar to what you've done for your database `insert`.

If your arrays are not multi-dimensional, try using PHP's [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode) to concatenate strings from arrays:

```
foreach($_POST as $var => $value) {

    // if this value is an array, implode it to a string
    if (is_array($value)) { $value = implode(", ",$value); }

    // output this var/value pair
    echo "<p>".$var.": <strong>".$value."</strong></p>";

}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QNC19n)

Comment: This method does not do any changes. I see the same output on email as before name: Krishna
dept: CS
email: sainth.r@gmail.com
phone: 9015518456
comments: 
model: Array
tag: Array
itemdesc: Array
Submit: Submit

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the code. I used your array structure and it's working here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/l48AMK

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building up the output yourself, use either `var_export` or `print_r`. That way, everything will be outputted and you don't have to worry about how deep the array ends up getting.

To output to the browser:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

To store in a variable:

```
$message = '<pre>';
$message .= print_r($_POST, true); // Notice that true is being passed as the second argument
$message .= '</pre>';
```

Comment: This method is giving the output as list of array instead of ordered content. Array
(
    [name] => Krishna
    [dept] => CS
    [email] => sainth.r@gmail.com
    [phone] => 9015518456
    [comments] => 
    [model] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell
            [1] => Apple
            [2] => HP
        )

    [outag] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1245
            [1] => 8798
            [2] => 1232
        )

    [itemdesc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Big
            [1] => Big
            [2] => Big
        )

    [Submit] => Submit
)